# What is the efficient way of counting 2 level nested model (using mongoid or MongoDB in general)?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, database

I have following data models. In which a Project embeds many ComponentDescriptor, and a ComponentDescriptor embeds many Statistic.

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :component_descriptors

  field :status, :type => Integer

  backgrounded :publish 
end

class ComponentDescriptor
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Acts::Tree

  embeds_many :statistics
  embedded_in :project, :inverse_of => :component_descriptors

end


class Statistic
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :statistics_type, :type => String
  field :data, :type => String
  field :playhead_time, :type => String
  field :remote_ip, :type => String
  field :user_agent, :type => String

  embedded_in :component_descriptor, :inverse_of => :statistics
end
```

The question is what is the best way to count the total number of Statistic object in a Project.

One way I can think of is looping through each ComponentDescriptor and count the number of Statistics objects and then sum them up. But I think this is not efficient way.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store the count field at the Project level that would be the most optimal and fastest way for you to obtain it.